# How to fix app crashing on IOS devices react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am building for first time an React - Native Application . Until now we have tested the application on the several Android devices and no problem has been detected . But when the application is runned on Ios devices it crashesh almost instantly . So my question is am i doing something wrong ? I followed up the documentetion from the react-native web page and i have done the right installs , but still the problem occurs . Also when i try to build up an Android or IOS simultaor with the command :

- react-native run-android

  - react-native run-ios

---

It throws me an error : 
Android project not found. Maybe run react-native android first?

Or for Ios :
iOS project folder not found. Are you sure this is a React Native project?

Error: iOS project folder not found. Are you sure this is a React Native project?

My folder looks like this :

[image]

Am i missing something that should  be installed ? Can you givev me some hints ? Thank you !

Comment: It is an `expo` project and not a pure `React Native`, so check expo docs.

Comment: Thanks to that ... i didn't know that expo is different than React Native . I think i can resolve my problems from the expo documentations . Cheers mate !

Answer (score 0):

PandaMastr, the example image indicates that this an expo react native application, to run it you will need to go the root folder and run npm start which will launch the application. In order to use the react-native run commands you would need to eject the application ( always make a backup so you can revert if need be ); which would then create the android and iOS folder and install the react-native run aspects you are attempting to use.